# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'cls' was called on null

Tags: flutter

How can I resolve the problem as below ?

I run my application normally, it's run well.

But when I've set break point, then tried to perform debugging my code.

It always shows the error messages which do not come from my code, debugger is interrupted as well.

> Unhandled exception:
>       NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'cls' was called on null.
>       Receiver: null
>       Tried calling: cls
>       #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
>       #1      BodyBuilder.lookupInstanceMember (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/body_builder.dart:1604:30)
>       #2      BodyBuilder.scopeLookup (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/body_builder.dart:1764:13)
>       #3      BodyBuilder.handleIdentifier (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/body_builder.dart:1700:12)
>       #4      Parser.ensureIdentifier (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:2165:14)
>       #5      Parser.parseSend (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:4932:32)
>       #6      Parser.parseSendOrFunctionLiteral (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:4675:12)
>       #7      Parser.parsePrimary (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:4233:14)
>       #8      Parser.parseUnaryExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:4172:12)
>       #9      Parser.parsePrecedenceExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:3961:13)
>       #10     Parser.parseExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/parser/parser.dart:3933:13)
>       #11     BodyBuilder.parseSingleExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/body_builder.dart:1111:20)
>       #12     SourceLoader.buildExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:327:21)
>       
>       #13     IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression. (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:795:61)
>       
>       #14     CompilerContext.runInContext..
>   (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:46)
>       #15     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
>       #16     CompilerContext.runInContext. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:19)
>       #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
>       #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
>       #19     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
>       #20     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
>       #21     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:121:12)
>       #22     IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:726:26)
>       
>       #23     IncrementalCompiler.compileExpression (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:156:23)
>       #24     FrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:527:44)
>       
>       #25     _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:frontend_server/server.dart:62:22)
>       #26     listenAndCompile. (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:812:20)
>       
>       #27     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
>       #28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
>       #29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
>       #30     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
>       #31     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
>       #32     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:236:11)
>       #33     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:150:13)
>       #34     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:125:5)
>       #35     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:163:5)
>       #36     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
>       #37     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
>       #38     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
>       #39     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
>       #40     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
>       #41     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
>       #42     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:236:11)
>       #43     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:241:7)
>       #44     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:312:20)
>       #45     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:305:5)
>       #46     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)
>       #47     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
>       #48     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
>       #49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
>       #50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
>       #51     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
>       #52     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
>       #53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
>       #54     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1786:41)
>       #55     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
>       #56     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
>       #57     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
>       #58     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
>       #59     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
>       #60     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
>       #61     new _RawSocket. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1335:33)
>       #62     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:856:14)
>       #63     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
>       #64     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
>       #65     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
>       #66     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)

My code:
**main.dart**
    void main() async {

```
  Flame.images.loadAll(<String>[
    'level0.jpg'
  ]);

  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
  MyGame game = MyGame ();
  runApp(game.widget);
 ....
```

**mygame.dart:**

```
......
      MyGame() {
        sprite = Sprite('level0.jpg');// Break point
      }
.............
```

note:

> ```
> I am using Android studio 3.1
> flutter veriosn 1.7.8
> channel stable
> ```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Where did you set the break point?

Comment: Did you instantiate the object you call `cls` on? It seems that you haven't.

Comment: @MohitShetty: I set by Android Studio

Comment: @flarkmarup: I do not use any object which contain cls variable. The error does not come from my source code.

Comment: I mean where in the code of AS did you set the breakpoint?

Comment: Insert the code snippet in the questions description and mark the place where you set the breakpoint.

Comment: @MohitShetty: plz take a look. Thanks!

Comment: You surely must have imported atleast one dart file

Comment: @MohitShetty: sure, it run well if I remove break point, I do not know what's wrong

Comment: Share the entire code of your main.dart file

Comment: @MohitShetty:oh, sorry. I cannot share entire code bcz security policy :(

Comment: Actually, you call `game.widget` but I cannot see it declared anywhere